# Mac Terminal show end of buffer

Tags: macos, terminal

When I call commands like man, it puts everything into a buffer and only shows one page at a time. I can navigate with my arrow keys or my space bar but I want it to show everything at once without me having to scroll through it. What do I need to do in order to change it? I'm pretty sure it's some key bind but I can't figure it out.

I would prefer it if it would simply just automatically scroll to the end. If there's some command I can enter to make it automatically do this, please let me know. If I have to use a key bind instead to make it scroll down to the end of the buffer, or send everything to the shell, then let me know.

If I'm doing a key bind, I'd prefer it to be something like shift/command + down to scroll all the way down. And then I'd probably map a similar one to go back up.

Thanks.

Comment: How do I get it so that it will always use this property. I tried it out and man -P cat <command> is what I want. But I want this to be the same as man <command>, so I don't have to type -P cat each time. What do I do to configure it to stay like this without typing the extra formatters? I'd also prefer to do it for PAGER instead of MANPAGER.

Also, while I'm here, I changed it to close terminal on exit but I also want it to kill the process and remove Terminal from my dock. Should I just be typing killall Terminal or can I configure exit to also end the Terminal process and get it off my dock

Comment: That's not how Terminal behaves; it's a multiwindow app. You should ask another question for that (short answer: don't use kill, use a tool like `osascript` or my own `appswitch` to ask the application to quit.)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `man`, it's piping your result through a pager.  If you haven't configured it, on the Mac this is `/usr/bin/less -is`.

One way to bypass the pager is by setting it to `ul`.  For example:

```
% man -P ul ls 
LS(1)                     BSD General Commands Manual                    LS(1)
[...]
```

`ul` is a filter that ensures boldface and underlining are preserved.  They're encoded in a rather archaic way by `X^HX` and `X^H_` respectively, which modern terminals don't support; pagers ordinarily translate these into terminal escape sequences by themselves.

With `man`, there are a couple of other options:

1. In OS X 10.5 and later, you can use
   the Help menu to get `man` pages. 
   Just press
   <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`/`</kbd>
   and type the name of the page you
   want, then select it from the menu (although I think this uses a
   fixed path unfortunately).  This
   just runs `man -P ul` for you in a new Terminal window.
2. Another is to render into
   PostScript, which OS X can convert
   into a PDF, nicely formatted for
   printing if you want. I've been
   using this `zsh` function for years:

   ```
    gman() {
      PDF=/tmp/man.$$.pdf
      print 'Converting to PDF...'
      man -t $@ | /usr/bin/pstopdf -i -o $PDF
      print 'Opening...'
      open $PDF
      { sleep 5; rm -f $PDF } &!
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the pager to `cat` instead of the default (`/usr/bin/less -is` on my machine) should do what you want.  From the [`man(1)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man):

> **-P** *pager*
>
> Specify which pager to use. This option overrides the **`MANPAGER`** environment variable, which in turn overrides the **`PAGER`** variable. By default, **`man`** uses **`/usr/bin/less -is`**.
>   '

So you can either do `man -P cat whatever`, or you can set `MANPAGER` and/or `PAGER` in your environment to `cat` and get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The `less` pager which is usually the default on most systems already has key bindings to go directly to the end and start of its input:

- `g` will go to the start of the input
- `G` (which would actually be something along the lines of `Shift+g`, unless you type with Caps Lock on) will go to the end of the input